# Specify location of g++ dependencies when compiling

Tags: c++, dll, g++, dependencies

So I'm using Anaconda to run Python 2.7 32-bit on my company's server.  That works dandy.  Anaconda came with MinGW, so I'm attempting to use the g++ compiler in there.  Everything works for me.  I can compile c++ source, and then run the resulting executable.  The issue comes when  coworkers try to do the same.  Apparently, the g++ compiler creates a dependency for the executable it makes on a particular dll located within Anaconda.  I have a path variable to where this dll lives, my coworkers do not, thus, they cannot run any executable made by g++.

Is there a way to specify where this dll dependency is when I compile executable so that anyone can use them?  Something like:

```
g++ someCode.cpp -o someCode.exe locationOfDll=path2dll
```

Just to be clear, everyone can successfully compile c++ source code, but only I can run the resulting executable.  Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that simply giving everyone the path variable is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help? It discusses updating the library search paths.

http://www.mingw.org/wiki/HOWTO_Specify_the_Location_of_Libraries_for_use_with_MinGW

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272383/linking-with-r-and-rpath-switches-on-windows which says otherwise there are not good solutions. I think.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: This plus my comment basically say if not, how else would you like to proceed?

Comment: So the answer was to put the dll in the same directory as the executable as the solution to the question @SeanPerry posted stated in his comment