# Is it possible to use a shared object constructor for setting the library search path?

Tags: c, shared-libraries, posix

I am storing shared objects in a hierarchical folder structure. Shared libraries can depend on one another. At runtime, shared library X may need to load shared library Y. I am unsure what mechanism I can use to have library X locate Y.

I'd rather not use -rpath because it doesn't translate well across platforms:

1. [How to set the runtime path (-rpath) of an executable with gcc under Mac OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4513799/how-to-set-the-runtime-path-rpath-of-an-executable-with-gcc-under-mac-osx)
2. [Is there a Windows/MSVC equivalent to the -rpath linker flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107888/is-there-a-windows-msvc-equivalent-to-the-rpath-linker-flag)

I can't put the shared objects in a single directory because of potential name clashes. LD_LIBRARY_PATH and PATH are not usable since I'd be adding a *lot* of paths.

This has me wondering whether I can modify the LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the [constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759880/automatically-executed-functions-when-loading-shared-libraries) of a shared object (using -Wl,-init). This would require the constructor to be run before the runtime linking happens. I couldn't find whether this is the case.

In essence, I'm thinking about doing the following (haven't tried this code out yet):

Add this function to the library source code:

```
extern char *searchPath;

void construct() {
    char *libPath = getenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH");
    char *new_libPath = malloc(1 + snprintf(NULL, 0, "%s:%s", libPath, searchPath);
    sprintf(new_libPath, "%s:%s", libPath, searchPath);
    setenv("LD_LIBRARY_PATH", new_libPath, 0);
}
```

And compile with:

```
gcc foo.c --shared -o foo -Wl,-init,construct
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, you cannot in general. Some linkers might support it, but others definitely won't. Many dynamic linkers will just ignore changes to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or equivalent after the main executable is loaded, so you may not even be able to influence the loading path at all at runtime. Other linkers may not even try to call initializers or constructors before all the libraries are linked (the Mac OS X `dyld` appears to behave this way, for example).

Furthermore, some linkers won't even load two libraries that have the same `soname`, as they would be considered the same library. So, considering that you have potential name clashes in your libraries, this would preclude even loading them automatically in the first place.

---

For runtime loading of libraries, POSIX provides `dlopen` and `dlsym`. `dlopen` lets you load an arbitrary library by file path, and `dlsym` lets you grab pointers to symbols defined within that library Consider using those instead of some dynamic path-changing hack - `dlopen` and `dlsym` are portable and reasonably easy to use. Yes, you don't get "automatic" symbol resolution (in that you have to `dlsym` everything yourself), but there are ways to design your libraries to make this easier (or use macros to make resolution easier).

On Windows, you can use `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` similarly. If you want a nice cross-platform library that smooths over the platform differences, consider something like [libltdl](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Using-libltdl.html).